# Why [1, 1, 2] | [] == [1, 2] is `true` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am not sure about how the binary OR operator works in Ruby with empty arrays, but it looks like it creates a Set from an array with duplicated elements.

Comment: It would help if you could explain what, *precisely*, is unclear to you about the documentation of `Array#|`. That way, a) we can avoid unnecessary work by explaining things you already know or explaining things you already read and didn't understand, and b) the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't stumble over the same problems you did. You would essentially make the world a better place! And who wouldn't want that?

Comment: Hello. As spickermann very well explained, it is the normal behaviour of Array#|. To me, it is counterintuitive, as a union of arrays (not sets) should include duplicates. So I would expect `[1, 1, 2] | [] == [1, 1, 2]`. But it is clearly stated in the documentation —I didn't see that. I don't intend to change Ruby, just wanted to understand how the operator internally worked. As by definition, it wipes any duplicates, as in spickermann's second example `[1,1,2,2] | [3] #=> [1,2,3]`.

Comment: The fact that you didn't see it in the documentation, is valuable feedback, because it is likely that other people may overlook it, too. So, it would make the documentation better to make it more prominent, e.g. pulling it out into a separate paragraph and emphasizing the words "excluding any duplicates". Ruby is a community-driven open source project, so we, the community, including you, and spickermann, and me, we are all "the community", and thus we are all in some sense "Ruby maintainers".

Comment: Thank you for your help, Jörg!

Comment: By the way, I believe the fact that Array#| is at the end of the methods list in the Array page, instead of with the rest of operators like <<, & or + at the beginning, makes it more difficult to find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This removal of duplicates has nothing to do with the second array being empty. It is the normal behavior of the [Array#|](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-7C) method and described in the docs:

> `ary | other_ary → new_ary`
>
> Set Union — Returns a new array by joining `ary` with `other_ary`, **excluding any duplicates** and preserving the order from the given arrays.
>
> It compares elements using their `hash` and `eql?` methods for efficiency.

Comment: _"This removal of duplicates has nothing to do with the second array being empty"_ seems a bit misleading to me. I'd say `ary | []` removes duplicates just _because_ the second array is empty.

Comment: @Stefan What I am trying to say is: `Array#|` will remove duplicates even when the second array is not empty: `[1,1,2,2] | [3] #=> [1,2,3]`

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe `ary | ary` would be a better example, as it doesn't add anything.

Comment: Another example: `[1,1,1] | [1,1] #=> [1]`

Answer (score 1):

According to ruby docs

> Set Union — Returns a new array by joining array with other array,
> excluding any duplicates and preserving the order from the original
> array.
>
> It compares elements using their `hash` and `eql?` methods for efficiency.

```
[ "a", "b", "c" ] | [ "c", "d", "a" ] 
#=> [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
```

[ary | other_ary → new_ary](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C)

Comment: Don't mind the haters. I gave you a +1. They might be upset by a lack of code formatting, or answering after spickermann had already delivered a really solid answer. Do try and avoid piling on unless you've got a new angle to add.